# The "Add A Comment" Button sometimes Freezes

Tags: bug, comments, live-refresh, javascript

Whenever I see a red banner stating:

> Stack Overflow requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. [Retry using another source.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie)

The "Add a comment" (blue link) button and the "Show 0 more comments" button freezes.
If I click on the button, nothing happens.
I have to refresh.

Also, if that red banner appears, the Stack Exchange icon on the top-right corner
puts me to the Stack Exchange main page instead of showing me a list of all 177 Stack Exchange sites.

If that red banner appears, spoiler blocks on Puzzling Stack Exchange will no longer stay shown after clicked.

Comment: The "add a comment" button is just the blue one below.

Comment: Things requiring JavaScript not working if JavaScript is not working isn’t unexpected. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). Do you see any errors or warnings? See the Network tab. Is there any resource not loading?

Comment: @user289905 "Show 0 more comments" should refresh the webpage in this case.